# mapDispatchToProps vs. store.dispatch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it more efficient to use `mapDispatchToProps` inside a component to call actions or is it more efficient to use `store.dispatch` inside action creators?

**`mapDispatchToProps` example:**

```
// Component

import React from 'React';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { defaultAction } from './actions';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  onClickHandler() {
    this.props.dispatch(defaultAction());
  }

  render() {
    return (<div onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this)} />);
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { dispatch };
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);



// Actions

import { DEFAULT_ACTION } from './constants';

export function defaultAction() {
  return {
    type: DEFAULT_ACTION,
  };
}
```

**`store.dispatch()` example:**

```
// Component

import React from 'React';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { defaultAction } from './actions';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  onClickHandler() {
    defaultAction();
  }

  render() {
    return (<div onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this)} />);
  }
}

export default MyComponent;


// Actions

import { DEFAULT_ACTION } from './constants';
import store from './store';

export function defaultAction() {
  store.dispatch({
    type: DEFAULT_ACTION,
  });
}
```

My guess is that it's more efficient to use `mapDispatchToProps` instead of importing the entire `./store` to dispatch actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally recommended to use `dispatch` as provided to you via `mapDispatchToProps`, and not to couple your action creator methods to your store singleton. [Here's some in depth discussion about it.](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/362#issuecomment-265009145)

Comment: Also related: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-multiple-stores and http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/ .

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for the great links! The second link didn't work for me, however.

Comment: @Kelsonic : ah, can you clarify "didn't work"? I know my website wound up on a couple web filter lists some years back - are you seeing some kind of "blocked" message" from a corporate web filter or something?

Comment: It comes up fine for me.

Comment: @markerikson Sorry, it was a proxy I'm using. The link works fine on normal networks.